# Magento shows tier price twice (in grid/list view)

Tags: magento-1.7, tierprice

I'm trying to figure out why prices on my magento eshop show up twice on the grid/list view. This only happens when i add a 'sale' price to the product. Is there any way to disable the 'al vanaf: €...' (meaning 'starting from') so it won't show anymore?

- sidenote: i use an ERP system to import products and determine the (tier)price .

[image: double pricing magento]

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have 2 instances of the code that calls the price.

Edit your **list.phtml**

Look for 2 instances of the following in the grid and list view:

```
<?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
```

Comment out one of them. Refresh. If it works remove the offending code.